# Netbeans puts folder in one location but looks for it in another

Tags: netbeans, path, filenotfoundexception, temporary-files

I cleared my temporary Java cache in an effort to repair the fact that a new, valid replacement code signing certificate was reading as expired.
Now, instead of saying that the application cannot be opened due to an expired certificate, it says 
under "wrapped exception:"
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https:[...]/ProjectName/lib/jsoup-1.6.0.jar
It is putting the lib/jsoup file in the dist file, but looking for it in the main directory.
If I switch it manually, it claims that the jsoup file is not signed - even if I switch it before signing the program in the command prompt.
Any suggestions on how to repair this issue?
Thank you!

Comment: Post the stack trace, correctly formatted.

Comment: Thank you. The issue is solved. The lib file was unnecessary and somehow was included when I had to reinstall Java to repair a non-functioning jarsigner which resulted from clearing my temporary Java cache to get it to recognize a new code signing certificate.  I appreciate your help skomisa.